# Google Maps v3 Listener (click) - Change URL

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a Google Maps map with a markercluster, and various points. Generating the points like below with the event listener, it goes off for every single point on page load.

```js
function mappyfuntime() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.481581,-3.17909),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("bigmap"), mapOptions);
    <?php echo prepare_javascript(); ?>
    var markers = [];
    var marker = [];
    linkto = new Array();
    for(g=0; g<LocationsArray.length; g++) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(LocationsArray[g][0], LocationsArray[g][1]);
        marker[g] = new google.maps.Marker({'position': latlng});
        markers.push(marker[g]);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker[g], 'click', click_handler(PermalinksArray[g]));
    }
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
}

mappyfuntime();
function click_handler(link) {
    alert(link);
}
```

However, if I change the google.maps.event.addListener to the following, the alert comes back undefined.

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(marker[g], 'click', function() {
    alert(PermalinksArray[g]);
});
```

And if I pass PermalinksArray[g] to the function, the same thing happens. Is there any way to get a piece of information from an array (which is globally defined) when its corresponding point is clicked on the map?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the Permalinks Array comes from the php insert? Well then its not in global scope. Try puttung that php-insert at the top of your javascript script.

```js
// set globals
var map;
var markers = [];
var PermalinksArray = ['...'];
var LocationsArray = ['...'];

function mappyfuntime() {

    // init map
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.481581,-3.17909),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("bigmap"), mapOptions);

    // create markers        
    for(g=0; g<LocationsArray.length; g++) {

        // create new Position
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(LocationsArray[g][0], LocationsArray[g][1]);
        // create new marker with position
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({'position': latlng});
        // add event to marker
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            click_handler(marker, PermalinksArray[g]);
        });
        // push marker into markers array
        markers.push(marker);
    }
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
}

function click_handler(marker, link) {
    alert(link);
}

mappyfuntime();
```

Comment: Did that, but PermalinksArray and g still come back as undefined once their in the function.  Using:   google.maps.event.addListener(marker[g], 'click', function(PermalinksArray, g) {
   alert(PermalinksArray[g]);
  });

Still pops up an alert with "undefined". Code is at http://fused.org.uk/mappy if you want to have a look.

Comment: The scope should not matter btw. you got the markers and marker twisted. you were using marker[g] and pushing markers into markers. if that makes any sense. You should create a marker and push it into the markers array.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Google Map with 2 markers and when a marker is clicked then the area's name appears in the info window. The information in the markers is loaded through a global defined array named cityList. You can find my code below.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
        <title>jQuery mobile with Google maps - Google maps jQuery plugin</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var cityList = [
                ['Chicago', 41.850033, -87.6500523, 1],
                ['Illinois', 40.797177,-89.406738, 2]
            ],
            demoCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(41,-87),
            map;

            function initialize()
            {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                   zoom: 7,
                   center: demoCenter,
                   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                 });
            }

            function addMarkers()
            {
                var marker, i;
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                for (i = 0; i < cityList.length; i++) 
                {  
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(cityList[i][1], cityList[i][2]),
                        map: map,
                        title: cityList[i][0]
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                        return function() {
                            infowindow.setContent(cityList[i][0]);
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                    })(marker, i));
                }
            }

            $(document).on("pageinit", "#basic-map", function() {
                initialize();
            });

            $(document).on('click', '.add-markers', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                addMarkers();
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="basic-map" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1><a data-ajax="false" href="/">jQuery mobile with Google maps v3</a> examples</h1>
                <a data-rel="back">Back</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">   
                <div class="ui-bar-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="padding:1em;">
                    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:350px;"></div>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="add-markers" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Add Some More Markers</a>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps.